# Why I can not draw pixel side by side pixel?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing, pixel

I want to draw a picture using Canvas in C#.
I have to have control of color of every pixel of picture, so I'm drawing it using Rectangle.

```
public void AddPixel(Canvas canvas, double x, double y)
    {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        Canvas.SetTop(rec, y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rec, x);
        rec.Width = 1;
        rec.Height = 1;
        rec.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        canvas.Children.Add(rec);
    }
```

It should be working, but when I want to check it and draw simply black picture:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
            {
                AddPixel(MandelbrotCanvas, x, y);
            }
        }
```

I get something like this - rectangles with something like borders, space between pixels:

[image]

Why? Someone could help me draw a clearly black picture?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with passing `5` instead of `y` to the `AddPixel` method?

Comment: I copied wrong code. This picture I get when I'm using AddPixel(..., x, y)

Comment: Try adding this: `rec.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);`. If that doesn't work, try adding `rec.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;`

Comment: Yes! It helps me, thanks a lot! Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: I would also like to suggest using [`WriteableBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  if you're making per-pixel drawings. In its current state, your method, which uses `Rectangle`s for making per-pixel drawings, may suffer from poor performance because you're creating and disposing 2500 UI elements every time you draw a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image reveals that there seems to be some level of [supersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling) (a method of spatial anti-aliasing) in place. Your 1px wide line becomes softer than it really is. Anti-aliasing helps with drawing angled lines that don't look "pixelated".

Supersampled line (zoomed in):

[image: Anti-aliased line]

Aliased line:

[image: Aliased line]

Set the [`RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make sure your rectangles aren't anti-aliased:

```
rec.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

If that doesn't work, try adding setting the [`UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
rec.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
```

I would imagine that this prevents [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) of your rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

This one helps me

```
rec.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```